# getInitialNotification not working on iOS

Tags: react-native-firebase

I am using `react-native-firebase` version `5.3.1`.
and pod Firebase/Messaging version `5.20.1`.

On iOS, `getInitialNotification` is always returning null. 
It is working fine on Android though.

`onNotification` and `onNotificationOpened` working fine on both platforms.

Should I enable remote notification from xcode capabilities ? (I tried and still no luck)

Here is my AppDelegate.m

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2015-present, Facebook, Inc.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 */

#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#if __has_include(<React/RNSentry.h>)
#import <React/RNSentry.h> // This is used for versions of react >= 0.40
#else
#import "RNSentry.h" // This is used for versions of react < 0.40
#endif
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import "SplashScreen.h"
#import "RNGoogleSignin.h"
#import "RNFirebaseNotifications.h"
#import "RNFirebaseMessaging.h"

#import <Firebase.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  [FIRApp configure];
  [RNFirebaseNotifications configure];

  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                   moduleName:@"wiy"
                                            initialProperties:nil];

  [RNSentry installWithRootView:rootView];

  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

  // Facebook react-native SDK
  [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                           didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

  [SplashScreen show];
  return YES;
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
  [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
  return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                        openURL:url
                                              sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                     annotation:annotation
          ] || [RNGoogleSignin application:application
                                   openURL:url
                         sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                annotation:annotation
                ];
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
  [[RNFirebaseNotifications instance] didReceiveLocalNotification:notification];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(nonnull NSDictionary *)userInfo
                                                       fetchCompletionHandler:(nonnull void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{
  [[RNFirebaseNotifications instance] didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings {
  [[RNFirebaseMessaging instance] didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
}

@end
```

Comment: I have the same issue on V7. Have you found any solution to this so far?